# Javascript window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue return with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode, html-editor, nodevalue

Hy... i dont really want to use other poeple editor...

i want to learn "how to create" not "how to use"

so i decided to create my own editor...

[My editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxTlJ.png)

its easy to create bbcode editor...
but when i try to create the HTML Version ( Live Preview & Editing )

i have a little problem ( may be my biggest problem )
Of course making a question is my last hope after searching...

anyway, my english is bad, so i hope you can understand what i'm saying.

Look, My Expectation VS Really

[Expectation VS Really](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncf8t.png)

And this is the simplest of my editor

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".buttonBold").click(function(){
  $(".editableDiv").focus();
  var help_me_anchorNode    = window.getSelection().anchorNode.nodeValue;
  var help_me_anchorOffset   = window.getSelection().anchorOffset
  var help_me_focusOffset   = window.getSelection().focusOffset
  var help_me_focusNodeValueLength  = window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue.length;
  var help_me_firstTag    = "<b>";
  var help_me_lastTag    = "</b>";

  if(help_me_anchorOffset > help_me_focusOffset){
   var help_me_firstTag   = "</b>";
   var help_me_lastTag   = "<b>";
  }
  window.getSelection().anchorNode.nodeValue = help_me_anchorNode.slice(0, help_me_anchorOffset) + help_me_firstTag + help_me_anchorNode.slice(help_me_anchorOffset);
  var help_me_focusNodeValue = window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue;
  if(window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue.length - help_me_focusNodeValueLength > 0) {
   help_me_focusOffset += window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue.length - help_me_focusNodeValueLength;
  }
  window.getSelection().focusNode.nodeValue = help_me_focusNodeValue.slice(0, help_me_focusOffset) + help_me_lastTag + help_me_focusNodeValue.slice(help_me_focusOffset);
 });

});
```

```css
.editableDiv{
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="buttonBold">Bold</button>
<div class="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
Double click this : HELPME
<br />
<br />
And then, click the "Bold" Button
<br />
The result will : &lt;b&gt;HELPME&lt;/b&gt;
<br />
Not : <b>HELPME</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.getSelection()` and `.surroundContents()`

```
$(".buttonBoldHtml").click(function(){
  $(".editableDiv").focus();

  var highlight = window.getSelection(),
      bold = $('<b/></b>')[0],
      range = highlight.getRangeAt(0);
  range.surroundContents(bold);
});
```

---

If you select partial nodes (when the highlighted text begins or stop between an open tag), you have to use [`extractContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents) :

```
$(".buttonBoldHtml").click(function(){
  $(".editableDiv").focus();

  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
      bold = document.createElement('b');
  bold.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(bold);
});
```

I've edited the demo and added a test with both bold and italic:

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vuhAIDoNkeLd3IvhEd8J?p=preview)

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.

When selected multiple line

Comment: wow... its work perfectly... but i still want to know... 

why you create element "span" ...

Thank you for your help ^_^

Comment: but i really sorry... my problem still not solved... thats why i use getSelection() & anchorOffset rather than exectCommand(); .... when i create popup for second attribute like <a href="{ATTRIBUTE}">{VALUE}</a>... pop up is needed for inputing the URL... and when i clicked the pop up... the focus are changed to the popup... so i need to detect the 
 selected text & focus offset & replace whole text with $().html("");

Comment: @JackRose It seems like a different problem to me, you should validate this and open an other question

Comment: im sorry, my bad... my problem solved hours ago... but still have a problem with the focus... Thanks for your help @Nicolas R ^_^